# Datetime is saving -5:30 in database

Tags: laravel, reactjs, datetime

I'm passing datetime to api from my application, but is is saving 5:30 less in database. I'm using laravel for api & react in frontend application.

My date format is, Thu Oct 12 2017 11:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST).

When I checked in database, it saved as 2017-10-12 05:30:00.

How can I save exact datetime ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

By default laravel set your application timezone to UTC, you have to configure the timezone in config/app.php as 'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata'

you can refer different timezones [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)

Comment: I have set timezone as 'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata'.